# prove this function is continuous on $\Bbb R$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Hi just need some help with the following question.

> Is the function
>   $$f(x)=
> \begin{cases}
> \displaystyle{\frac{e^x-2^x}{x+x^3}},&\text{for $x\neq 0$}\\
> 1-\ln 2,&\text{for $x=0$}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   continuous on $\Bbb R$?

I'm just confused with what theorem to use to prove it. I've tried putting the two equal to each other and computing the limit as $x$ approaches zero but I'm not sure if thats the right thing to do?? Any hints/advice would be great, thanks.

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EycuO.png)

Comment: $g(x)=(e^x-2^x)/(x+x^3)$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ \ $\{0\}$ so $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$ iff $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)=f(0)=1-\ln 2.$

Answer (score 4):

The function $$f(x)=\frac{e^x-2^x}{x+x^3}$$ is clearly continuous for all $x\neq 0$. Now, using the L'Hospital's Rule we get
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-2^x}{x+x^3}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^x-2^x\ln 2}{1+3x^2}=1-\ln 2=f(0)$$ which shows that $f$ is continuous at $x=0$.